# Wrong method call?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a method that invokes some action on Dispatcher.

```
public static object Invoke(Dispatcher dispatcher, Action method)
    {
        try
        {
            ValidateArgs(dispatcher, method);
            return dispatcher.Invoke(method);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception
            Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Dispatcher (in System.Windows.Threading) has a void Invoke method defined, that takes Action parameter.

```
public void Invoke(Action callback)
        {
            Invoke(callback, DispatcherPriority.Send, CancellationToken.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
        }
```

Now the piece of code I have, compiles locally, however throws an exception on Build Server (TeamCity 5) with the error message - ***Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'***

This made me wondering why does it compile on my local machine, however fails to do so on Build Agent. When I hover my mouse over Invoke method, intellisense shows that it's gonna call Invoke method that has a return parameter, and takes 2 parameters - Delegate, and object[].

[image]

So this lefts couple of questions I can't figure out

1. Why it's not failing to compile on my local machine? That's what I would expect (this is not the code I wrote, I inherited it). There is a type (**Dispatcher**) and a method that is being called on that type (**Invoke**), by passing parameter (**Action method**). There is such method defined in the type, with return type of void, shouldn't that method be selected? Why it chooses another method to call. I'm not talking about method overloading here, as I know that return type is not a part of method ***signature***, and while overloading methods, method signature is being considered.
2. Since the source code is the same on my local machine and on Build server, and compilation is failing on build server, what's the difference between these 2 environments? Is it some kind of a compiler switch/config, or what is being considered that let's same code to compile in one environment and fail in another?

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling on the build server, your code is calling the overload [`void Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which does not return a value, therefore the `return` statement cannot compile (there is nothing to return).

That method is only available starting from .NET 4.5, while on earlier versions [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compatible with the way you are calling it is the one shown in the IntelliSense screenshot.

In a nutshell, the problem is that your own system and the build server compile targeting different versions of .NET. The overload added in 4.5 is a better match for the call site as per the overload resolution rules but unfortunately it turns the call site into an invalid statement.

Comment: thanks, you're right, I changed target platform on my local machine, and it failed to compile. Confusion came from the fact, that I decompiled the Dispatcher class, and I could see void Invoke(Action), so I thought it's there for .net 4.0.